# VBA Error 3075 When Filtering Between Dates

Tags: date, ms-access, vba, filtering

I know that there are a lot of answered questions regarding this topic but none of them answer the following question:
I have got this little and simple code:

```
Private Sub btnHwEOLNext2_Click()

Dim filterString As String
Dim startDate As Date
Dim endDate As Date

startDate = Date
endDate = Date + 730

filterString = "[HW End of Support] BETWEEN '" & startDate & " And " & endDate & "'"

Me.Filter = filterString
DoCmd.SetOrderBy "[HW End of Support] ASC"
Me.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

all i am trying to do is to filter between 2 dates. the `startDate`date will always be the day you use the form and the `endDate` will always be 730 days after `startDate`

why do i keep on getting

> error 3075

? Help please!

Comment: Have you tried using `#` instead of a single quote?

Comment: It would also help us help you if you provide the *text* of the error message, not just the number! And also indicate which *line of code* is triggering the error.

Comment: The `filterString` results in `[HW End of Support] BETWEEN '11.04.2018 And 10.04.2020'` it looks like quotes are missing

Comment: Can you try like this -> `"[HW End of Support] BETWEEN "" & startDate & "" And "" & endDate & ""`

Comment: @Vityata i get a runtime error 3464, missmatch in criteria expression

Comment: @RaulGonzales - then something like this - `"[HW End of Support] BETWEEN #" & startDate & "# And #" & endDate & "#"`

Comment: @Vityata i dont get an error now and it runs but is filtering by all dates in 2020 when what it should do is filter dates up to 11/04/2020?

Comment: @RaulGonzales - probably this is Format issue, thus `11/04` is translated as `4.November`. Can you put `14.November 2020` and see whether it is filtered as well?

Comment: @RaulGonzales - the easiest way to go around the format without lots of thinking is this one - `"[HW End of Support] BETWEEN #" & Format(StartDate,"MM-DD-YYYY") & "# And #" & Format(EndDate,"MM-DD-YYYY") & "#"`

Comment: @Vityata that one worked mate! thaks a lot! if you put it in an answer i will mark it accordingly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the date between `#` signs, then VBA considers it as a date.

As far SQL is using American date system with `MM-DD-YYYY`, you can change the format between the `#` signs, before parsing:

```
"[HW End] BETWEEN #" & Format(sd,"MM-DD-YYYY") & "# And #" & Format(ed,"MM-DD-YYYY") & "#"
```